# How to handle event soft keyboard hidden?

Tags: android, fragment, android-softkeyboard

My note application has 2 fragments on a screen: A list of notes fragment and a note detail fragment to display the selected note in the second fragment, it has an input text field (`android:inputType="textMultiLine"`). As I want to handle event keyboard hidden so I can save the change user has made when they close the keyboard. Can anyone give me a clue to do this task?

Comment: by default the android soft keyboard will provide you a done key. Onclick of this done key, keyboard automatically hides

Comment: But i can't use 'done' key  because the text field is multiple line and i must use the 'enter line' key instead . can you help me more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how i handle it on my Note Detail fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_note_detail_of_style_searching, container , false);

    listviewFilter = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_filter);
    noteDetailView = view.findViewById(R.id.note_detail_of_style_view);
    photoDetailView = view.findViewById(R.id.gv_note_detail_photo);

    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {                
            int heightDiff = view.getRootView().getHeight() - view.getHeight();
            if (heightDiff > 200) { 
                isWatchingKeyboard = true;
                photoDetailView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return; //must exit now
            }

            if(isWatchingKeyboard){
                isWatchingKeyboard = false;
                viewForFocus.requestFocus();
                photoDetailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    return this.view;
}
```

Comment: The above works for me, but be careful of the magic number 200 on bigger devices, such as Nexus 5. The value was 217.

Comment: 1 - not that clean, 2 - what is`isWatchingKeyboard`?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best and universal solution for keyboard issue, is measure the VisibleDisplayFrame on layout change:

```
Rect visibleRect = new Rect();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup mMain = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_cover_album, container, false);

    mMain.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(visibleRect);
    mMain.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v,
                                       int left,
                                       int top,
                                       int right,
                                       int bottom,
                                       int oldLeft,
                                       int oldTop,
                                       int oldRight,
                                       int oldBottom) {

                Rect r = new Rect();
                mMain.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                if(r.height() < visibleRect.height()){
                    //keyboard shown

                }
                if(r.height() == visibleRect.height()){
                    //keyboard hidden
                }

            }
        });

        return mMain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
private int prevBottom;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status, container, false);
    prevBottom = view.getBottom();

    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (view.getBottom() > prevBottom) {
                view.requestFocus();
            }
            prevBottom = view.getBottom();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

and added this to the view I was inflating:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

and this to the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```